# Redraw subviews programmatically on orientation change

Tags: ios, swift, subview, orientation-changes

I have created all of my subviews in a UiViewController programmatically.
When the device rotates i want to recreate the entire layout of the UiViewController so i write the bellow line inside the viewDidLoad()

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "rotated", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

The problem is that the method rotated is called multiple times.

Why this happens?

Also what is the appropriate way to recreate the entire layout of the UiViewController programmatically?

Comment: where you added/register notification observer viewDidload or Viewwillapprar? If you have added in viewwillappear or viewdidappear then you have to remove the same on viewwilldisappear or viewdidDisappear

Comment: i have done that..

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> When a rotation occurs for a visible view controller, the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:, willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:, and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: methods are called during the rotation. The viewWillLayoutSubviews method is also called after the view is resized and positioned by its parent. If a view controller is not visible when an orientation change occurs, then the rotation methods are never called. However, the viewWillLayoutSubviews method is called when the view becomes visible. Your implementation of this method can call the statusBarOrientation method to determine the device orientation.

So do it in the "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:" method.